# What to call a method that calls itself asynchronously?

Tags: terminology, asynchronous-programming

In UI-related code, I often end up writing a construct like this:

```
function doItOnceAndRepeat() {
    if (!stillNeededToDoIt()) {
        return;
    }
    doIt();
    runLater(doItOnceAndRepeat, 1000);
}
```

`runLater` is a function that will execute the specified function asynchronously, after some time. It might be `setTimeout` in Javascript or `postDelayed` in Android.

Is there a name for this? It may look like a recursion, but there won't be multiple invocations in the stack.

Also, what could be a better name for `doItOnceAndRepeat` that better explains this mechanism?

Comment: Perhaps *asynchronous tail-call recursion*.

Comment: There's no dedicated name for this construct (AFAIK). Call it like above or self-rescheduling task. Be creative :-)

Comment: There is no asynchronous execution in JavaScript, however there is delayed or scheduled execution.  Asynchronous is term referring to a property or quality describing the nature of code execution relative to the threading model.  Since JavaScript is single threaded, the term doesn't apply.

Comment: @ErikEidt no, asynchronous means that what you see won't get executed now. By not having multiple thread Javascript have less problem du to concurrency. However it is perfectly psosible than a callback relying on a variable from outside scope can has toruble because the value has changed in the interval between the start of the function and the execution of the callback.

Comment: @Walfrat, I understand that there are lots of opportunities for callbacks to observe different state, due to other callbacks and event handlers.  Still, async implies concurrency, and concurrency in cooperatively-scheduled single-threaded environment is dubious.

Comment: @ErikEidt I just wanted to point to future readers that even if it's not multithreaded, you can still have some trouble if you're not carefull.

Comment: @Walfrat, totally agree.

Comment: I'd call it "bad practice"

Comment: It is "delegated re-invocation". Technically it is not recursion because it is not the same execution path revisiting.

Answer (score 3):

My two cents: you might want to call the function with a name that describes *what* it does rather than *how* it does it.

It works better as self-documenting code and you decouple the name of the function (and the name users of that function have to remember) from the implementation.

Alternatively, if your function sbazzles the foo, you could call it `sbazzleFoo` and pass it to another function called `runAndSchedule` that takes `sbazzleFoo`, runs it and schedules its delayed execution if needed.

Comment: So `runAndSchedule(sbazzleFoo)` can be contained in a function called `startFooSbazzling`?

Comment: If your program's logic calls for it, I don't see why not.

Answer (score 3):

Asynchronously recursive.

Can't get much clearer than that. This clearly documents that it is recursive in an asynchronous fashion. Try not to over-think the matter :)

Comment: I don't think this is recursive, strictly speaking. The function doesn't call itself, it just arranges for itself to maybe be called in the future.

Comment: That's why he calls it "Asynchronously recursive". It's like the lazy postman who worked until 2pm and then threw the remaining letters into the nearest postbox :-)